# Code Build with S3 Maven Repository

Tags: git, maven, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-codebuild

I set up a Code Build project which deploys my artifacts to S3, from where I use them as Maven Repository for other builds. So in my dependent project there is something like:

```
<repositories>
<repository>
<id>S3Repository</id>
<name>My S3 Repository</name>
<url>https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/my-bucket/root/.m2/repository</url>
</repository>
</repositories>
<dependencies>
```

The bucket itself has a bucket policy, which is ip-restricted, and allows my own ip, as well as 35.157.127.248/29, which are all code build ips from my region (I'm using eu-central-1).

when I build my code locally, it works like a charm, dependencies are fetched from s3 and compiled.

When I try the same over CodeBuild, I get constantly a

Access denied to: https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/my-bucket/repo/root/.m2/repository/com/foo/bar/pom.xml ReasonPhrase:Forbidden

only way to make it work is to allow public access (which I don't really want to do).

I was displaying the ip during the build, and the machine got the 35.157.127.254, so I definitely got the IP range right. But when I check the access logs of my bucket, I get some 10.0.x.x with an access denied.

I also gave my code-build-role all rights I could think of, including admin. No changes. Still access denied.

I also tried to add S3 as trusted entity/relationship. But did not get better by that (in fact, that seems to be illegal as AWS complains it should just have one entity there).

The only way for me to get it work at the moment is over a Nat gateway, but that is way to expensive just for this little feature.

I also tried a different bucket policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1533804673095",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1533804667143",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::codebuild-service-role"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket"
        }
    ]
}
```

But sadly also that did not help.

Anybody can help me with that?

Thank you